# Laravel policy returning unexpected 403

Tags: laravel

In my controller

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Account;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->authorize('view', auth()->user());

        return view('account.index');
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $this->authorize('update', auth()->user());

        return view('account.settings');
    }
}
```

In UserPolicy

```php
public function view(User $user, User $model)
{
   return $user->id === $model->id;
}

public function update(User $user, User $model)
{
   return $user->id === $model->id;
}
```

This always returns a 403, even if I put `return true` in the action. What am I missing?

I have also tried this:

```php
$user = User::findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);
$this->authorizeForUser(auth()->user(), 'update', $user);
```

With the same result.

Answer (score 1):

have you linked the policy to the model in **AppServiceProvider**

```
  protected $policies = [
        User::class => UserPolicy::class,
    ];
```

Comment: You mean AuthServiceProvider I think? I thought Laravel auto-discovers these policies as long as you stick to the naming convention which I have done with UserPolicy. Other policies actually work and are not registered in AuthServiceProvider. But I’ll try this!